# PhantomJS page.evaluate returns undefined when using a bridge

Tags: javascript, meteor, phantomjs

I am trying to follow some tutorials, a simple console log to get the title of the page, however returns undefined, any idea why is this happening?

```
var phantom = Meteor.npmRequire('phantom');
phantom.create(function(ph){
  ph.createPage(function(page){
    page.open('http://m.bing.com', function(status) {
        var title = page.evaluate(function() {
            return document.title;
        });
        console.log(title);
        ph.exit();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) bridge between PhantomJS and node. Its API is different from PhantomJS in that each function or property that you call/set takes a callback and so does `page.evaluate` for when the result is ready.

The example in the README on GitHub directly shows your intended code:

```
phantom.create(function (ph) {
  ph.createPage(function (page) {
    page.open("http://www.google.com", function (status) {
      console.log("opened google? ", status);
      page.evaluate(function () { return document.title; }, function (result) {
        console.log('Page title is ' + result);
        ph.exit();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because page.evaluate is async. Maybe try wrapping it in a `Future`-ized function

```
var title = (function(page) {
    // not sure about Meteor.npmRequire... so I'm using Npm.require instead
    var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future'); 
    var future = new Future();

    page.evaluate(function() {
        future.return(document.title);
    });

    return future.wait();
})(page);
console.log(title);
```